# Error with dlib and face_recognition library

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, dlib

I am getting an error while importing the face_recognition library. I have tried using a Virtual Environment too. Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\face_recognition-1.3.0-py3.8.egg\face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\face_recognition-1.3.0-py3.8.egg\face_recognition\api.py", line 17, in <module>
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'
```

Version: Python 3.8
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Could you please explain what this has to do with C++?

Comment: Sorry. Wrong Tag. New here.

Comment: If you are new, I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the face database `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks`, you need to download it and unzip it and put it in the folder where your code is located

Face Library Download Link:http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

Comment: What is the new error that you are getting, according to me it should work

Comment: Same as before. Should I link it to the code and if so how should I? New error added - File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Achu\Python-Codes\Ida\Ida (Text-based Assistant).py", line 32, in <module> import cv2, face_recognition

Comment: The above solution worked for me but you can refer this if you are still not getting it http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection.py.html

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. I finally settled on using OpenCV2 for face_recognition.